# How to implement Raffle ticket system for android / webserver stack

Tags: android, ajax, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am making an android app with a raffling system. The user logs in via google OAUTH and then performs a certain action in the app, where they will earn a raffle ticket. This data is sent via POST request to my backend server which will store the ticket number. Is there any way to prevent malicious users from spoofing fake requests to increase their tickets?

My idea so far - use the google OAUTH login system to generate a unique token and then send the token to my server. I will use Passport.js or some other means to verify the validity of the google token. If valid, update the database.

Any suggestions or criticisms or new ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, ended up using a UUID as a token to check validity. Encrypted of course.